# Is every powerful number the sum of a powerful number and a prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory, goldbach-type-problems, powerful-numbers

A positive integer $n$ is called *powerful* (OEIS: [A001694](https://oeis.org/A001694)) if $p^2$ divides $n$ whenever $p$ is a prime that divides $n$. Equivalently, $n$ is powerful if $n = a^2b^3$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

**Conjecture**: If $n$ is a powerful integer greater than one, then there is a prime $p$ and a powerful number $m$ such that $n=m+p$.

This conjecture holds for every powerful number $\leq 1000$. Given its similarity to the [Goldbach conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture), my suspicion is that this might be quite difficult to prove. Any references/ideas/partial results on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is false for $n=4,8$.

Comment: @Wojowu $2$ is not powerful. $8 = 1 + 7$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The $2$ was a typo. Other than that, didn't realize $1$ is powerful. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Wojowu By convention, $1$ is considered powerful, and since $4-1=3$ and $8-1=7$, the conjecture holds for these values.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I cited one of your [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93380/efficient-computation-of-the-trajectory-of-roots-of-a-parameterized-polynomial/93397#93397) in a recent [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379517300253).

Comment: Confirmed up to $10^6$ (using SageMath).

Comment: It is true for all powerful numbers $< 10^7$.

Comment: Would it follow from abc conjecture ?

Comment: Several sequences related to this seem not to be in the OEIS, but probably should be.  For example,  the powerful numbers $n$ such that $m+p = n$ with $m$ powerful and $p$ prime has only one solution: I get $4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 36, 64, 196, 324, 676, 10404$ and no others $< 10^7$.

Comment: Sequence A133364 is relevant.  Every positive integer $< 10^7$ except $1$, $2$ and $5$ can be written as $m + p$ with $m$ powerful and $p$ prime.   The obvious conjecture is that this is true for all positive integers except $1$, $2$ and $5$.  The positive integers $n < 10^7$ for which $m+p = n$ has exactly one solution are $3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 16, 17, 22, 24, 25, 26, 31, 36, 58, 64, 76, 82, 120, 170, 193, 196, 214, 324, 328, 370, 412, 562, 676, 730, 10404$.

Comment: The fact that so large a number as $10404$ manages to be the sum of a powerful number and a prime in only one way ($343 + 10061$) makes me suspect that this conjecture, if true, may be even harder than Goldbach.

Comment: Hardy and Littlewood conjectured (in "Partitio Numerum III") that every sufficiently large non-square is the sum of a square and a prime.  This would settle all cases except for small powerful numbers and large square numbers.  (Not that this conjecture is anywhere close to being resolved; as noted above, it is probably harder than the even Goldbach conjecture.)

Comment: If the first definition is used, then it is by convention; it definitely satisfies the second definition. Interestingly, the proof given on the Wikipedia page on the equivalence of the definitions relies on the prime factorization, which is only valid for integers greater than one.

Comment: Edited, thank you! (I added that remark from an earlier comment.)